# Scala SBT refresh error

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

When I am trying to add Akka dependency using sbt I was getting below error,

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Couldn't run: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/E:/Personal/Scala%20Workspace/AkkaTest/,akkatest)),This,This,This),update)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Don't know why I was getting error.

I have deleted my existing .ivy folder manually and rerun sbt but still having the issue.

I am using Scala 2.11.7 and Java 8.

Comment: Have you tried it in a directory without a space in the path?

Comment: No I haven't tried it. Let me do that as you said and will come back to you.

Comment: Hi @joescii , I tried it without space in path nut still no luck. it is still not working. :(

Comment: It would be useful to see your `build.sbt` and the output of the `last` command after the exception happens.